# Why does popping off my stack return garbage instead of the initial variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

When I run my program, it pushed numbers into the array perfectly fine. But when it pops them, and then prints them, I get garbage numbers. Does the problem have to do something with my main function?
Or did I not initialize my array correctly in my Stack class? I had some problems with my constructor at first, but it seemed to work fine after making some adjustments.

Is there anything that stands out as to why I am receiving the garbage numbers after running my script?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#ifndef MYSTACK_H
#define MYSTACK_H

#include<iostream>
#include<new>
using namespace std;


class MyStack
{
private:
    int *list;
    int top;
    int max;
public:
    MyStack(int m)
    {
        int max = m;
        list = new int[max];
        int top = -1;
    }
    ~MyStack()
    {
        delete[] list;
    }
    int push(int);
    int pop();
    int peek(int &a) const;
};

int MyStack::push(int a)
{
    if (top < max - 1)
    {
        top = top + 1;
        list[top] = a;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int MyStack::pop()
{
    if (top > -1)
    {
        top = top - 1;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int MyStack::peek(int &a) const
{
    if (top > -1)
    {
        return(list[top]);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

#endif

int main()
{
    MyStack m(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        int x = 1 + rand() % 100;
        cout << x << "\t";
        m.push(x);
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        int x;
        m.peek(x);
        cout << x << "\t";
        m.pop();
    }
    cout << "\n";
    system("pause>nul");
}
```

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). BTW, your `list` name is confusing. Better use `arr` or `tab` ... since it is *not* a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type))

Answer (score 3):

`top` and `max` are not set after calling constructor of `MyStack`, you are creating local variable and members are not affected:

```
int max = m; // local 
list = new int[max];
int top = -1; // local
```

change to

```
max = m;
list = new int[max];
top = -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameter `a` is never used in your `peek()` function:

```
int MyStack::peek(int &a) const
{
    if (top > -1)
    {
        return(list[top]); // you return the value instead of assigning it to "a"
        return 0; // unreachable by the way
    }
    return -1;
}
```